# Running a script to move a row in a Sheet the second time alters the 2nd Active cell location after deletion of the 1st row. Preventable?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a simple script that will move a row from one sheet to another when data is entered into a cell in the first column. After it is moved, the row is deleted. It works fine until you enter data into a second row before the script finishes from the first row. Because the first row is deleted, when the script runs for the second time, the active cell changes. Instead of row 2 moving, row 3 moves since it is now the new row 2. I could have it subtract a row from the active range, but it is possible the user could enter data into row 5 or 6 and not row 2. Is there a way to keep the focus of the active cell on the second row, even if row(s) above it are deleted?

If not, is there another approach that would work better?

```
            function WeeklyCallMoveToScheduled(){

              var columnNumberToWatch = 1;

              var sheetToSkip1 = "Master";

              var sheetToSkip2 = "Dropdowns";

              var sheetToSkip3 = "Contacted";

              var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Scheduled";

              var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2 = "Contacted";

              var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

              var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

              var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

              if (sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip1 && sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip2 && sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip3 && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue().indexOf('Scheduled') > -1) {

                var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);

                var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
                //add new row to target sheet
                targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow());

                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),20).setValue(sheet.getName());
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),19).setValue(new Date());
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),1).setDataValidation(null);
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),1).setBackground("#d9ead3");
                sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
                sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());

                }
              else if (sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip1 && sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip2 && sheet.getName() != sheetToSkip3 && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue().indexOf('Contacted') > -1) {

                var targetSheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo2);

                var targetRange2 = targetSheet2.getRange(targetSheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
                //add new row to target sheet
                targetSheet2.insertRowAfter(targetSheet2.getLastRow());
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),20).setValue(sheet.getName());
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),19).setValue(new Date());
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),1).setDataValidation(null);
                SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range.getRow(),1).setBackground("#fff2cc");
                sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange2);
                sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
              }
            }
```

Comment: Please share your script.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In addition to sharing your script, would you also share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information).

Comment: I am not able to share G docs outside of my organization, but I could email an excel version if you want to see it. Basically there are several User sheets where data is input and when the user selects a status from the drop down in column A the row is moved to the Scheduled or Contacted sheet based on their selection. I added the code to my original post.

Comment: "I am not able to share G docs outside of my organization" You don''t share your actual spreadsheet, you share a copy of it with all the private and confidential information removed). Doesn't seem to be any real difference between that and emailing an excel spreadsheet. You severely limit the opportunity for people to consider your problem and propose an answer when there is no spreadsheet to work from.

Comment: Are you familiar with [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)? Probably onEdit, in this case.

Comment: I do have this set up to run on an On Edit trigger. I tried sharing the spreadsheet publicly and I simply didn't have the option. I have tested sharing with a link, and it does require me to approve it, but it does work. Must be a GSuite setting somewhere limiting me from just making it public. Here is a link to a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bKbc-wTVEBu5gVVMDgtx0fnHs3WZbuces9xjArkuXBg/edit?usp=sharing